# Is there a "sticky post" function built into Craft?

Tags: entries

How would I make a post(s) sticky so that it appears first in the results and does not repeat later in the results?

Comment: FYI, your three comments are really all extensions of your original question. I'd recommend editing your question to include the entire train of thought... otherwise, you're really only having a conversation with yourself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could add a custom lightswitch field or similar and order your entries by that field.

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('news').order('myLightswitch desc') %}
```

If you need additional sort options, @Brad [just shared](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/2146/125) how to do that with SQL in the `order()` parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Answer update for Craft 3, and also adding in a secondary orderBy so that remaining entries are still ordered by date:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('news').orderBy('myLightswitch desc, postDate desc').all() %}
```

Without the secondary orderBy, I have no idea what it's using for the remainder sort order but it's not postDate in my testing at least!