# List Categories by 0-9 and A-Z

Tags: templating, categories, array, group

I'm trying to output a list of Brand names grouped by first letter. But some items have a number or symbol in the name. I want to list first the Numbers and symbols under 0-9 and the rest of the brands under A-Z

Like this:

**0-9**

- +People
- 10 Days
- 2Two
- 40 Weft
- 55 DSL
- 81hours

**A**

- Acne
- Adidas

**B**

- B.Young
- etc etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To group by the first letter you would simply use the [`slice`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/slice.html) filter within Craft's [`group`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/filters#group)
filter.

For all non letter characters you can now use Craft's [`replace`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/filters#replace) filter (it does regex since Craft 2.2)
and replace them with whatever you want these entries to be sorted by.

```
{% set entriesGrouped = entries|group('title|slice(0, 1)|upper|replace("/[^A-Z]/", "0-9")') %}

{% for letter, entriesInGroup in entriesGrouped %}
    {{ letter }}
    {% for entry in entriesInGroup %}
        {{ entry.title }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: OK, that's MUCH nicer ;). Wasn't aware of the fact that slice can be used within group ...

Comment: I found out some days ago, that you can even go crazy and do things like ternary in there: [Sorting entries A-Z, ignoring 'The' and grouping by first letter](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/8665/125)

Comment: Nice. Very elegant!

Comment: Better to add | upper

{% set entriesGrouped = entries|group('title|slice(0, 1)|replace("/[^a-zA-Z]/", "0-9") | upper') %}